# Responsive jQuery Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I have created a responsive menu that breaks at 480px and below. I have it to where the following reacts if:

1. The user clicks on a the "Menu" link.
2. The menu slideToggles out.
3. The sub-menus slideToggle out onClick as well.
4. But you cannot click on any of the pages.

Does this have something to do with the return false?

You may view the example here: http://www.stlredtails.com/construction/

You may need to resize the browser at or belw 480px to see the responsive navigation in action.

Here is the jQuery for the navigation:

```
jQuery(".navigation ul").hide();
jQuery("#navigation").click(
    function() {
       jQuery(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle(150, "swing");
       return false;
    }
);
jQuery(".navigation > ul > li").click(
    function() {
       jQuery(this).children("ul").slideToggle(150, "swing");
       return false;
    }
);
```

Thank you all!

Comment: I actually get a different bug at certain sizes: If the menu breaks to several lines but before it collapses to a column menu, some submenus appear below the following menu items.

Comment: Try clicking on the Sub-Menu items. Like Mission Statement and Board. It toggles the parent menu and slides it back up without going to to the proper link.

Comment: The column menu works for me perfectly. In the multiline menu said links are overlapped.

Comment: Works fine for me, looks awesome might I add

Comment: News works for me but Teams doesn't (doesn't seem like there is a link for them yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the `return false`. When you're clicking the links, you're also clicking the ancestors `li` and `ul`. Before the link "activates" the functions bound to the ancestors click event execute. Since they `return false` the default browser behavior (navigating away) is prevented.

There are better solutions for this kind of menu behavior, but using what you already you have (and assuming you won't be changing your html) you can simply add the following to your javascript:

```
$('.navigation').on('click', 'a:only-child', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This searches for all links in the navigation menu that are the only child of their parents (which in this case, happen to be the links you want to continue working as links) and prevents the ancestors click events from executing - the `return false` shouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: Thank you this, and thank you for your explanation. But for some reason, this breaks my code. I have not a clue why though.

Comment: Hey Aaron. I guess you've copy pasted it, right? I wrote the code on jsfiddle which for some reason places an invisible character at the end of the code. If you backspace at then end of the last line ("});") apparently nothing will happen, but you'll be deleting that character. From then, the code should run without a problem.